# Does a Tor exit node change when a new Tor cct is assigned?

Tags: exit-relays

If say Tor changes circuits every few minutes, and lets say you have a session open with a HTTPS site (probably doesn't matter if http or https), say a bank or Facebook, twitter etc, when a cct changes, does that circuit change too which would imply the site you are visiting now sees a new IP address as the exit node has changed or does this cct change ONLY affect NEW connections you make?